# Is there an engine for MySQL/MariaDB that enforces CHECK?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I know that InnoDB enforces foreign key. Is there a engine for MySQL/MariaDB that really implements CHECK?

Suppose I create a table with the following command:

`create table a(t timestamp not null, check (t > '2014-05-01')) ENGINE=InnoDB;`

and I try to insert a row that is suppose to be invalid:

`insert into a(t) values('2014-01-01');`

MySQL, using InnoDB, allow the insertion of that invalid row. I would like to use an engine that would not accept that insert. Is there an engine for that job?

Comment: I don't believe there is, but a potential solution has been posted [here][1]


  [1]: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/9668

Comment: You can always upgrade to Postgres (SCNR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CHECK constraint works as expected in MariaDB 10.2, which is currently beta.
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-7563

Comment: That is awesome news.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such engine in MySQL. If you must check at the database level, your only option is to use triggers and validate the data there.

Maybe one day though:
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=3464